# how to prevent vb.net application from lag

Tags: .net, vb.net

My application became a big app and have multiple functions over time , basically it filter , and do some code for warehouse items , and each section/Genre have special functionality.

so when i put files and click start buttons it freezes instead of using timer .. because some files have over 3000 lines

how i can make a waiting instead of the app freeze , Like web apps and big apps like Vpns etc..

my timer code is basic , count file lines that is the max number, and after applying my code to each line adding 1 to variable:

```
Private Sub BtnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   For Each line In textbox1.text
   #Alot of code
   next
   dim x as integer= ProgressBar1.value
   x += 1
   ProgressBar1.value = x

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You will need to look into multithreading or asynchronous programming. That's too broad a topic for us to go into here and there isn't just one correct approach to your specific problem. You will need to do some general research, decide on a course of action and then you can ask us about specific issues with the implementation.

Comment: `For Each line In textbox1.text` If this is your actual code you are processing each character in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Threading is almost certainly the answer, and it can get complex.  I just literally posted a working example of using threading on another question a couple of minutes ago ([richtextbox for = i multiple function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798498/richtextbox-for-i-multiple-function/61800629#61800629)).  That OP wanted to run 2 threads at once until all shell commands in a richtextbox had been processed.

This code works and does exactly that; I hope it gives you at least a starting point on things to explore further.  Depending on your needs, you could use the `WHILE` loop to update your progress bar as each thread completes work.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Dim Thread1 As Thread
    Dim Thread2 As Thread
    Dim Thread1cmd As String = ""
    Dim Thread2cmd As String = ""
    Dim Thread1Running As Boolean = False
    Dim Thread2Running As Boolean = False
    Dim LastCmd As Int32 = -1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LastCmd = -1
        While LastCmd < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count
            If Thread1Running = False And (LastCmd + 1) < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
                LastCmd += 1
                Thread1cmd = RichTextBox1.Lines(LastCmd)
                output.Text += LastCmd.ToString + " Thread 1: " + Thread1cmd + vbCrLf
                Thread1 = New Thread(AddressOf Thread1Helper)
                Thread1.IsBackground = True
                Thread1.Start()
            End If
            If Thread2Running = False And (LastCmd + 1) < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
                LastCmd += 1
                Thread2cmd = RichTextBox1.Lines(LastCmd)
                output.Text += LastCmd.ToString + " Thread 2: " + Thread2cmd + vbCrLf
                Thread2 = New Thread(AddressOf Thread2Helper)
                Thread2.IsBackground = True
                Thread2.Start()
            End If
            'Note - there is debate around the DoEvents that follows, so experiment with it and see what works best for you
            Application.DoEvents()
            'the main thread now sleeps to give helper threads time to do some work:
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        End While
    End Sub
    Sub Thread1Helper()
        Thread1Running = True
        Dim p1 As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            p1 = New System.Diagnostics.Process
            Dim MyCMD As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "\cmd"
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = MyCMD
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c " + """" + Thread1cmd + "&&PAUSE" + """"
            'MsgBox(p1.StartInfo.FileName.ToString)
            p1.Start()
            p1.WaitForExit()
            p1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Thread1Running = False
    End Sub
    Sub Thread2Helper()
        Thread2Running = True
        Dim p2 As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            p2 = New System.Diagnostics.Process
            Dim MyCMD As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "\cmd"
            p2.StartInfo.FileName = MyCMD
            p2.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c " + """" + Thread2cmd + "&&PAUSE" + """"
            'MsgBox(p2.StartInfo.FileName.ToString)
            p2.Start()
            p2.WaitForExit()
            p2.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Thread2Running = False
    End Sub

End Class
```