# richtextbox for = i multiple function

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for the answer to my question, here I clearly explain the situation to you.

I have a richtextbox, and 10 lines included.

line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
..
line10

and i am doing this;

```
For i = 0 to richtextbox.Lines.Count = - 1
    Button1_Click;
    Dim getlist as Process = Process.Start("cmd", "commands" + richtextbox.Lines(i))

    getlist.WaitForExit()
Next
```

I tried this but it didn't work;

```
Dim getlist as Process = Process.Start("cmd", "commands" + richtextbox.Lines(i))
Dim getlist2 as Process = Process.Start("cmd", "commands" + richtextbox.Lines(i + 1))
```

when I do this, it gets like;

first: richtextbox line 0 and line 1

and getlist starts line1 and getlist2 starts line2

I want it to be like;

**getlist: line0
getlist2: line1**

and who finishes earlier, the function starts to get new line;

for example:

**getlist: line0-line2-line3-line5
getlist2: line1-line4-line6**

how could I do this? thanks a lot for all answers!

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_Arguments

Comment: I don't get clicking a button in your loop. Can you move the code in the button to its own Sub and call it from the button and your loop?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you'll need to use some sort of threading-based solution to execute in parallel.  Probably the most straightforward of these is to use `Task`-based asynchronous methods.

This would end up looking something like this:

```
Dim T1 = Task.Run(Sub()
                      Dim getlist as Process = Process.Start("cmd", "commands" & richtextbox.Lines(1))
                      getlist.WaitForExit()
                  End Sub)
Dim T2 = Task.Run(Sub()
                      Dim getlist as Process = Process.Start("cmd", "commands" & richtextbox.Lines(2))
                      getlist.WaitForExit()
                  End Sub)
```

Then, you would be able to use various approaches to wait for one or both tasks to finish.  If you mark the containing routine as `Async` you could `Await` either `T1` or `T2`.  You can also `Await Task.WhenAny` to continue as soon as either one finishes.

I would strongly recommend reading the MSDN documentation on Task-based asynchrony.  In particular, you should read "Implementing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern", as the sections on Interleaving and Throttling are likely to be applicable to what you want to do.  Unfortunately, the examples are all in C# in my copy of the online help, but the material should be straightforward to translate to VB.

Comment: Hello, firstly thanks for your comment.  I got the `Await Task.WhenAny`, I turned my `Private Sub` to `Private Async Sub` so I could use Await, and I am not a perfect English speaker, that's why I can not get the MSDN documentation properly. I am really sorry to say to you that, but;

Comment: Oh sorry, mistakenly clicked enter :D 
here is the recent code now

`For i = 0 To richbox.Lines.Count - 1

       Dim T1 = Task.Run(Sub()
                              Dim getlist As Process = Process.Start("cmd", richbox.Lines(0))
                              getlist.WaitForExit()

                          End Sub)
        Await Task.WhenAny
Next`

Comment: With this code, How the code understands first start with 0, and then when its finished goes with 1 ? because with ` for i = 0` code when I change the process dim as `richbox.Lines(i)` it goes orderly 0-1-2-3 all the lines, but I want it multiple for example at the same time 2-3 cmds or until how many I can, but if I put 3 lines into richbox, 3 line cmd must start at the same time, shouldn't try for 4 (for cpu usage)

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention, this is the perfect application for threading.  This works - I just wrote it, compiled it and ran it.  To see it do some simple tasks in separate threads, running just 2 threads at a time until all commands have been executed, just enter valid shell commands into your richtextbox1.  To test it, I used:

- Echo A
- Echo B
- Echo C
- Echo D

NOTES:

- I appended a PAUSE into the CMD arguments, so you can see clearly what's happening.
- Threading has a lot of nuances that I can't begin to get into here such as ApartmentState, but it's something that you'll want to educate yourself about.
- I'm no guru, and I'm sure there are some more elegant ways to handle some of this

Hope this helps!

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Dim Thread1 As Thread
    Dim Thread2 As Thread
    Dim Thread1cmd As String = ""
    Dim Thread2cmd As String = ""
    Dim Thread1Running As Boolean = False
    Dim Thread2Running As Boolean = False
    Dim LastCmd As Int32 = -1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LastCmd = -1
        While LastCmd < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count
            If Thread1Running = False And (LastCmd + 1) < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
                LastCmd += 1
                Thread1cmd = RichTextBox1.Lines(LastCmd)
                output.Text += LastCmd.ToString + " Thread 1: " + Thread1cmd + vbCrLf
                Thread1 = New Thread(AddressOf Thread1Helper)
                Thread1.IsBackground = True
                Thread1.Start()
            End If
            If Thread2Running = False And (LastCmd + 1) < RichTextBox1.Lines.Count Then
                LastCmd += 1
                Thread2cmd = RichTextBox1.Lines(LastCmd)
                output.Text += LastCmd.ToString + " Thread 2: " + Thread2cmd + vbCrLf
                Thread2 = New Thread(AddressOf Thread2Helper)
                Thread2.IsBackground = True
                Thread2.Start()
            End If
            'Note - there is debate around the DoEvents that follows, so experiment with it and see what works best for you
            Application.DoEvents()
            'the main thread now sleeps to give helper threads time to do some work:
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        End While
    End Sub
    Sub Thread1Helper()
        Thread1Running = True
        Dim p1 As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            p1 = New System.Diagnostics.Process
            Dim MyCMD As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "\cmd"
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = MyCMD
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c " + """" + Thread1cmd + "&&PAUSE" + """"
            'MsgBox(p1.StartInfo.FileName.ToString)
            p1.Start()
            p1.WaitForExit()
            p1.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Thread1Running = False
    End Sub
    Sub Thread2Helper()
        Thread2Running = True
        Dim p2 As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            p2 = New System.Diagnostics.Process
            Dim MyCMD As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + "\cmd"
            p2.StartInfo.FileName = MyCMD
            p2.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c " + """" + Thread2cmd + "&&PAUSE" + """"
            'MsgBox(p2.StartInfo.FileName.ToString)
            p2.Start()
            p2.WaitForExit()
            p2.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Thread2Running = False
    End Sub

End Class
```